# Why is 0 (zero) printed without leading "0x" with C printf format "%#x"?

Tags: c, hex, printf

Background: I have a number of scripts that parse log files looking for hex numbers by finding the leading "0x". Our embedded C library changed to a new printf. The new printf is more standards compliant than our previous and my scripts broke.

On a Linux box:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
    printf( "%#010x\n", 0 );
    printf( "%#010x\n", 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

Output (using glibc) is:

```
0000000000
0x00000001
```

Output on our firmwware was:

```
0x00000000
0x00000001
```

From printf(3), on the '#' flag character:
"For x and X conversions, a nonzero result has the string "0x"  (or "0X" for  X  conversions) prepended to it."

I'm curious *why*. Without digging through the C standards documents or buying lunch for standards committee members, why not a leading 0x on a zero valued argument?

Comment: Wild guess: 0 is 0 regardless of base, so there's no need to specify it.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can get the behavior of *always* including a leading `0x` by writing `"0x%08x"`, whereas the standard-described behavior would be trickier to get from a library that *always* included the leading `0x`. Maybe the standards committee was optimizing for a harder-to-get-otherwise case, rather than for the absolutely most common case? (Of course, you can't change `"%#10x"` to `"0x%8x"`, but then, it's hard to imagine someone wanting to see `0x0` with no zero-padding.)

Comment: There's no mention of this in the [C89 Rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/title.html) (HTML) or in the [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The standard seems to be written this way:

- `%#x` and `%#o` try to guarantee that the output can be parsed correctly using `strtol` with `base = 0`.
- In these cases, the `#` flag adds *as few extra characters as* possible. For example, 0 is printed as `0` because there is no need to add the extra `0x`. This makes a lot of sense if you do *not* specify the minimum field width and 0-padding.
- If you wanted to add `0x` always, you could often simply write something like `0x%x`. Hence `%#x` would seem to be useful *only* in those special cases in which you really *want* the special handling of 0.  But the pre-pending of `0x` doesn't work well with default field width specifiers eg) `0x%12x`is right justified by blanks between the 0x and hex digits, which is unlikely to be what's wanted in that case.  For this case an extra preparatory pass with sprintf would be required, so a hex string like `"0x2ac2"` can be white space right justified with something like `printf( "%12s", hexstr);` Fortunately justifying with `0` rather than spaces using something like `printf( "0x%012x", hexstr);` works as expected producing valid hex digits for a parser.

Now the way `%#x` is specified to work makes a lot of sense in isolation. And the way something like `%010x` is specified to work makes a lot of sense in isolation. You are combining these two modifiers, and the end result is, arguably, strange.  For another application, like auto generating neat C code to initialise tables, having `0,` rather than `0x0` is not an issue.

But there is no need to combine `%#x` and `%010x`. You could just write `0x%08x` to do what you want.

Comment: And after posting the answer, I noticed that @ruakh had already given essentially the same information in a comment. Apologies.

Comment: +1. There's no need to apologize. Answers are better than comments. I posted my thoughts as a comment, rather than an answer, because I knew they couldn't be complete; but your answer is much more thorough, and makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Both answer and comments are appreciated! The idea of being compatible with strtol makes sense. Now time for me to go change a lot of code to 0x%08x.

Comment: Why doesn't `1` have this behaviour too? It's just as unambiguous as `0`. There is no need to add the extra `0x`.