# Cannot update pointer value

Tags: c

I may have a fundamental misunderstanding about how pointers work, but I thought I could assign a variable value to a pointer, however whenever I print the dereferenced value of the pointer it is always 0 rather than the value of 'timestamp'.

```
volatile uint32_t *myAddress = (volatile uint32_t*)0x12341234;

uint32_t timestamp = 0x1111;

*myAddress = timestamp;
```

Comment: you need to use a valid pointer, see my answer

Comment: What would the address `0x12341234` point to?

Comment: What made you believe that you are allowed to write anything a `0x12341234` address?

Answer (score 4):

> Cannot update pointer value

You mean cannot update pointed value

Doing

> ```
>  volatile uint32_t *myAddress = (volatile uint32_t*)0x12341234;
>
>  uint32_t timestamp = 0x1111;
>
>  *myAddress = timestamp;
> ```

you use the (very probably) invalid address `0x12341234`, to deference it has an undefined behavior

Do something like that :

```
uint32_t v;

volatile uint32_t *myAddress = &v;

uint32_t timestamp = 0x1111;

*myAddress = timestamp;
// now v values 0x1111
```

---

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  uint32_t v = 0;

  volatile uint32_t *myAddress = &v;

  uint32_t timestamp = 0x1111;

  *myAddress = timestamp; // now v values 0x1111

  printf("0x%x 0x%x\n", (unsigned) v, (unsigned) *myAddress);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0x1111 0x1111
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: hello @chqrlie I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513169/why-is-0-zero-printed-without-leading-0x-with-c-printf-format-x few minutes ago :-) I didn't know that exists before

Comment: `%#x` will convert an `unsigned int` value to hexadecimal representation with a `0x` prefix unless the value is `0`. It is not strictly equivalent to `0x%x` but handy for debugging purposes.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, I see that in the question I put the link, frankly the interest is very limited, not sure that deserves the time to implement it in the lib and document it^^

Comment: In hindsight, many standard C library functions could have been specified differently and some would never have made it to the Standard... such as `gets()` and `strncpy()`.

Comment: about what you like, again a [min/max problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55985097/2458991), that time I reverses the order as you like (if I remember well) ^^

Comment: I was just trying to let Bathsheba make his/her point about the order of argument...

Answer (score 0):

```
volatile uint32_t *myAddress = (volatile uint32_t*)0x12341234;
```

this kind of fixed address pointers are in common use in the uC development to access the memory mapped hardware registers or the memory at the exact address.

for example:

(ARM STM32)

`volatile uint32_t *initialSP = (volatile uint32_t *)(0x8000000);`

```
#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)
GPIOA -> MODER = value;
```

The address has to have the physical sense - ie it has to be valid.

Your probably is not and you get the hardware or memory fault.