# Taking 2 values out of 3 from main function

Tags: c

So I have a problem using functions in C. I need to make a `max` and a `min` function to find the maximum and minimum value. In the `main` function I need to load 3 numbers (`x`, `y`, `z`) and I have a formula to solve. It goes: `y = 2 * Min(x, y) / Max(x, Min(y, z))`. How can I get only 2 numbers to compare which is max or min if I have 3 numbers? I am getting the error that there are few values declared in `Min` or `Max`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Max(int x, int y, int z) {
    if (x > y && x > z) {
        return x;
    } else
    if (y > x && y > z) {
        return y;
    } else
        return z;
}

int Min(int x, int y, int z) {
    if (x < y && x < z) {
        return x;
    } else
    if (y < x && y < z) {
        return y;
    } else
        return z;
}

int main() {
    int x, y, z;
    float rez;

    printf("unesi vrijednosti x, y i z: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);

    if (x >= -10 && x <= 10 && y >= -10 && y <= 10 && z >= -10 && z <= 10) {
        rez = (2.0 * (float)Min(x, y)) / ((float)Max(x, (float)Min(y, z)));
        printf("%.3f", rez);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "How can I get only 2 numbers to compare which is max or min if I have 3 numbers?" - how to find the minimum or maximum of _two_ numbers? Your formula requires that `Min` and `Max` take _two_ arguments, not three.

Comment: Change `Min` and `Max` to `int Min(int a, int b)`, and `int Max(int a, int b)`. The functions don't need three parameters, only two. And the function parameters can have any name.

Comment: Maximum and minimum have the interesting property that duplicating arguments does not change the result of the function. Looking at binary `max()`: `max(a, max(a, b))` is always the same as `max(a, b)`. See **idempotence**.

Comment: why do you define min/max getting 3 args to after call them with only 2 args ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your code, you should extract a [mcve] and include the error message verbatim as reference in your question.

Answer (score 3):

> I am getting the error that there are few values declared in Min or Max.

because you define the Min/Max functions with **3** parameters but in `(2.0 * (float)Min(x, y)) / ((float)Max(x, (float)Min(y, z)));` you only give **2** arguments.

Just define them with 2 parameters, for instance

```
int Max (int x, int y)
{
   return (y > x) ? y : x;
}

int Min(int x, int y)
{
   return (y < x) ? y : x;
}
```

There is no interest to have more than 2 parameters, else why only 3 rather than 4 or 5 etc ? To have 2 parameters allows to manages all the cases just placing the calls as argument to an other

`max(a1,a2 ... ,an)` is `max(a1, max(a2, ... max(an-1, an))...)`

and of course same for *min*

---

Out of that I encourage you to check `scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);` returns 3 to be sure 3 valid values was entered

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass more or less perimeter to a function. You should pass 3 perimeter or you should declare both function with 2 perimeter. If u still want to have 3 perimeter in your function then you can pass value in function `Min()` and `Max()` like that:

for `Min()` call the function as:

```
Min(value1, value2, INT_MAX);
```

`INT_MAX` will always greater than any **integer** value. so it will make no difference in counting the minimum value.

And Same like this for `Max()` you can call the function as:

```
Max(value1, value2, INT_MIN);
```

**Remember:** You should `include <limits.h>` to use `INT_MIN` & `INT_MAX`

**OR,**

You can simply declare 2 function with 2 perimeter like below:

```
int Max (int x, int y) 
{
    if(x > y){
        return x;
    }
    else{
        return y;
    }
}

int Min(int x, int y) 
{
    if(x < y){
        return x;
    }
    else{
        return y;
    }
}
```