# printf: why doesn't %x print leading 0x (as opposed to %a)?

Tags: c, printf, conversion-specifier

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%a\n", 1.0);
    printf("%x\n", 93);
}
```

outputs:

```
0x1p+0
5d
```

Why not `0x5d`?

Does someone know the rationale?

Note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8513169/1778275) question is not exactly the same since it is about `%#x`.

Reason of the question: for `%x` cannot always "feed it back to C in initializer":

```
$ cat t324.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf(X);
}

$ gcc t324.c -DX="\"double x = %a;\", 10.0" && ./a.exe | gcc -xc - -c
<nothing>

$ gcc t324.c -DX="\"int x = %x;\", 10" && ./a.exe | gcc -xc - -c
<stdin>:1:9: error: ‘a’ undeclared here (not in a function)
```

Comment: Error '"\"double x = %a;\n\""" does not relate to posted code.  There is no `a`.  Is the `%x` getting messed up with shell?

Comment: This is not a language-lawyer question (tags edited).  No question or controversy has been raised about how the language specification should be interpreted.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, I want `10.0`, thanks! Updated. Tested on both on `bash 4.3.48(1)` (Linux) and `bash 4.4.12(3)` (Cygwin).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed, this is not a language-lawyer question.

Comment: pmor, Is the first output still `<nothing>`?  Try adding `puts(X);` to see what code really is getting for the format in the `printf()`.

Comment: Note also that `printf` output generated with `%x` can absolutely be fed back correctly to C, provided that `scanf` with `%x` (or `%X`) is used to read it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, of course. I've just forgotten to mention "in initializer". Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"%a"`, `"%A"` leads with `"0x"`, `"0X"` to help distinguish it from decimal output of `"%f"`, `"%e"`, `"%g"`, `"%F"`, ...
Note `"%a"` instead of say `"%e"`, affect 2 parts, the *prefix* and the *base* letter: `"0x"` and `"p"` instead of `""` and `"e"`.
`"%a"` came along well after memory prices dropped.

`"%x"` leads without a prefix as often code needs to concatenate hex output as in `printf("%08x%08x", a32, b32);`  It is trivial to prefix with `"0x"` then as in `"0x%08x%08x"`.  Not prefixing hex output as the default was certainly more common, back in the day (1970s) as every bytes [costs](https://jcmit.net/mem2015.htm).

Using `#` with `"%x"` as in `"%#x"` does not *always* prefix output.  The prefix occurs (in the same case as digits) when the value is non-zero.

For clarity, I find a lower case `x` and uppercase hex digits useful.

```
//       v------ lower --------v
printf("0x%08X\n", 0u-1u); // 0xFFFFFFFF 
//           ^-- upper ---------^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Although it's certainly a valid use case for `%x`, I think concatenating mutliple outputs is a much more specific rationale than is necessary or appropriate.  More generally speaking, sometimes you want the prefix and sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have option to have 0x or not. When you use `%x`, you receive the raw hexadecimal number. But when you use `%#x`, you receive the hex number with the `0x` prefix. What you choose depends on situation.

Comment: "But when you use %#x, you receive the hex number with the 0x prefix." --> Not quite.  Try `printf("%#x\n", 0);`

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [@Jack05](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18325090/jack05), the '#' character makes the difference. The manual of [printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) explains the conversion:

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %, and ends with
> a conversion specifier.  In between there may be (in this order) zero or more
> flags, an optional minimum field width, an optional precision and an optional
> length modifier.
> The overall syntax of a conversion specification is:
>
> ```
>       %[$][flags][width][.precision][length modifier]conversion
> ```

If the flag character is set with '#', then:

> For x and X conversions, a nonzero result has the string
> "0x" (or "0X" for X conversions) prepended to it.

For the 'a' or 'A' conversion,

> the double argument is converted to hexadecimal notation
> (using the letters abcdef) in the style [-]0xh.hhhhp±d;
> for A conversion the prefix 0X, the letters ABCDEF